# PHP Create multidimensional array with parser

Tags: php, arrays, parsing, multidimensional-array

I have a parsed html data fetched with `@file_get_contents($url)` which is like

```
<script type="text/javascript">var stock = 
new Array();
stock['704'] = new Array('92 (1-2)', 913, 'n.A.', '104 (3-4)', 2371, 'n.A.', '116 (5-6)', 1921, 'n.A.', '128 (7-8)', 4626, 'n.A.', '140 (9-10)', 4222, 'n.A.', '152 (11-12)', 4281, 'n.A.');
stock['101'] = new Array('92 (1-2)', 3444, 'n.A.', '104 (3-4)', 10136, 'n.A.', '116 (5-6)', 18834, 'n.A.', '128 (7-8)', 30662, 'n.A.', '140 (9-10)', 28981, 'n.A.', '152 (11-12)', 25982, 'n.A.');
stock['540'] = new Array('92 (1-2)', 505, 'n.A.', '104 (3-4)', 1220, 'n.A.', '116 (5-6)', 1634, 'n.A.', '128 (7-8)', 1381, 'n.A.', '140 (9-10)', 3187, 'n.A.', '152 (11-12)', 5014, 'n.A.');
stock['700'] = new Array('92 (1-2)', 401, 'n.A.', '104 (3-4)', 724, 'n.A.', '116 (5-6)', 1078, 'n.A.', '128 (7-8)', 1247, 'n.A.', '140 (9-10)', 2767, 'n.A.', '152 (11-12)', 2207, 'n.A.');
stock['448'] = new Array('92 (1-2)', 517, 'n.A.', '104 (3-4)', 727, 'n.A.', '116 (5-6)', 1721, 'n.A.', '128 (7-8)', 1537, 'n.A.', '140 (9-10)', 2382, 'n.A.', '152 (11-12)', 1820, 'n.A.');
stock['423'] = new Array('92 (1-2)', 876, 'n.A.', '104 (3-4)', 1110, 'n.A.', '116 (5-6)', 5196, 'n.A.', '128 (7-8)', 3159, 'n.A.', '140 (9-10)', 7727, 'n.A.', '152 (11-12)', 3656, 'n.A.');
stock['121'] = new Array('92 (1-2)', 781, 'n.A.', '104 (3-4)', 13363, 'n.A.', '116 (5-6)', 13300, 'n.A.', '128 (7-8)', 1964, 'n.A.', '140 (9-10)', 3591, 'n.A.', '152 (11-12)', 2552, 'n.A.');
stock['719'] = new Array('92 (1-2)', 188, 'n.A.', '104 (3-4)', 1313, 'n.A.', '116 (5-6)', 2109, 'n.A.', '128 (7-8)', 2076, 'n.A.', '140 (9-10)', 2292, 'n.A.', '152 (11-12)', 2674, 'n.A.');    var imageTmp = new Array();
</script><body>
```

final output which i require is MultiDimensional Array which needs to be like this. The values like 92 (1-2) could be alphabets as well.

```
Array
(
    [704] => Array
        (
            [92 (1-2)] => Array
        (
            [qty] => 913
            [price] => n.A

        )
            [104 (3-4)] => Array
        (
            [qty] => 2371
            [price] => n.A

        )
            [116 (5-6)] => Array
        (
            [qty] => 1921
            [price] => n.A

        )       
        )

    [101] => Array
        (
            [92 (1-2)] => Array
        (
            [qty] => 3444
            [price] => n.A

        )
            [104 (3-4)] => Array
        (
            [qty] => 10136
            [price] => n.A

        )
            [116 (5-6)] => Array
        (
            [qty] => 18834
            [price] => n.A

        )       
        )

    [700] => Array
        (
            [XS] => Array
        (
            [qty] => 3444
            [price] => n.A

        )
            [L] => Array
        (
            [qty] => 10136
            [price] => n.A

        )
            [S] => Array
        (
            [qty] => 18834
            [price] => n.A

        )       
        )

)
```

how could i get this

Comment: @alvin-brown welcome! Alvin you must be more specific in your question....

Comment: Do you have influence on "the source"? I.e. can you change the script on the other server that provides the data?

Comment: I dont have any control on other server. the input string is parsed from html.

Answer (score 1):

You probably print an array on a page, and you then fetch the contents of that page using `file_get_contents`. Your problem is that the content is not an array?

A quick solution to this is that you output the array as an [serialized](http://php.net/serialize) string. You can then simply do [unserialize](http://php.net/unserialize) to have a workable array again.